# Compound interest calculator giving incorrect answer

Tags: c, math, nested-loops

I have written a program to calculate compound interest.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <math.h>                                                               

int main(void) {                                                                 
    float value, rate, years,r;                                                     
    int column = 0, tmp;                                                            

    printf("Enter money values: ");                                                 
    scanf("%f",&value);                                                             

    printf("Enter a interest rate: ");                                              
    scanf("%f",&rate);                                                              

    printf("Enter number of years: ");                                              
    scanf("%f",&years);                                                             

    printf("\nYears  ");                                                            

    tmp = rate + 4;                                                                 
    r = rate;                                                                       

    for (int a = rate; a <= tmp; a++) {                                              
        printf("  %d  ", a);                                                         
        column++;                                                                   
    }                                                                               

    for (int b = 1; b <= column; b++) {                                              
        printf("\n  %d",b);
        for (int i = 1; i<= column; i++) {
            printf(" %.2f ", (float) pow ( (value)*(1.0+((r/100.0)/(1.0))) , (1.0*b))
            r++;
        }                                                            
        r = rate;
        printf("\n");
    }                                                                               
    
    // I = P*R*T                                                                    
    // P= AMOUNT (value)                                                            
    // R=RATE (r)                                                                   
    // T=YEARS (b)                                                                  
    return 0;  
}
```

It asks the user for a value (money), interest rate, number of years and displays the interest rate like so:

```
Enter money values: 100
Enter a interest rate: 6
Enter number of years: 5

Years    6    7    8    9    10  
  1 106.00  107.00  108.00  109.00  110.00 

  2 11236.00  11449.00  11664.00  11881.00  12100.00 

  3 1191016.00  1225043.00  1259712.00  1295029.00  1331000.00 

  4 126247696.00  131079600.00  136048896.00  141158160.00  146410000.00 

  5 13382255616.00  14025517056.00  14693280768.00  15386240000.00  16105100288.00
```

But my problem is the floating point calculation.
As you may be able to tell the numbers in the output above and very long and have many trailing digits
which i am very confused about.

For example in the 2nd row the first output is **11236.00**,
this is wrong since it should be outputting *112.36* but for some reason the decimal has moved
forward two spaces. Why is this? and how could i fix this problem and print the correct solution
with the decimal in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `value` inside the `pow`. So when you square for two years, you are squaring the amount. Move the `(value)*` to output the `pow` call.

Comment: thank you so much i dont know how i didnt spot that, could you please explain to a noob like me how you were able to do that so quickly?

Comment: @printf being imprinted with the compound interest formula at an early age helps. It may sound sarcastic, but I'm not joking. It was back in a time when school taught, you know, personal finance.

Comment: hm interesting i thought it was more practice but fair point

Comment: @printf Granted, the *rapdily* growing numbers were a dead give away something was wrong with the calculation. The only large number that could contribute to that extreme a climb is the value; the rest are business as usual, so it is highly likely the value usage is the culprit.

Comment: ahh yea that makes much more sense thanks! =P